# How to set value of datepicker in react native formik?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to use react-native-datepicker in a Formik form.

I Have

```
               <Formik
                initialValues={inits}
                validationSchema={() =>
                  yup.object({
                    username: yup
                      .string()
                      .nullable()
                      .required("Kamu belum memasukan Username"),
                    nama: yup
                      .string()
                      .nullable()
                      .required("Kamu belum memasukan Nama Lengkap"),
                    nik: yup
                      .string()
                      .nullable()
                      .required("Kamu belum memasukan NIK"),
                    no_telp: yup
                      .string()
                      .nullable()
                      .required("Kamu belum memasukan Nomor Telphone"),
                    email: yup
                      .string()
                      .nullable()
                      .required("Kamu belum memasukan Email"),
                    alamat: yup
                      .string()
                      .nullable()
                      .required("Kamu belum memasukan Alamat"),
                  })
                }
                enableReinitialize={true}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                  console.log(values);
                }}
              >
                {({
                  handleChange,
                  handleSubmit,
                  values,
                  errors,
                  setFieldTouched,
                  touched,
                }) => (
                  <View>
                    <InputText
                      name="username"
                      label="Username"
                      placeholder="Username"
                      // keyboardType="numeric"
                      onChangeText={handleChange("username")}
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("username")}
                      value={values.username}
                      errors={errors}
                      touched={touched}
                    />

                    <InputText
                      name="nama"
                      label="Nama Lengkap"
                      placeholder="Nama Lengkap"
                      // keyboardType="numeric"
                      onChangeText={handleChange("nama")}
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("nama")}
                      value={values.nama}
                      errors={errors}
                      touched={touched}
                    />

                    <InputText
                      name="nik"
                      label="NIK"
                      placeholder="Nomor Induk Keluarga"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      onChangeText={handleChange("nik")}
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("nik")}
                      value={values.nik}
                      errors={errors}
                      touched={touched}
                    />

                    <View>
                      <InputText
                        name="tgllahir"
                        label="Tanggal Lahir"
                        placeholder="test"
                        onChangeText={moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
                        value={moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
                        errors={errors}
                        touched={touched}
                      />
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={style.formIcon}
                        onPress={() => setOpen(true)}
                      >
                        <Image source={calendar} />
                        <DatePicker
                          modal
                          mode="date"
                          open={open}
                          date={date}
                          onConfirm={(date) => {
                            setOpen(false);
                            setDate(date);
                          }}
                          onCancel={() => {
                            setOpen(false);
                          }}
                        />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                    <InputText
                      name="no_telp"
                      label="Telphone"
                      placeholder="Telphone"
                      keyboardType="numeric"
                      onChangeText={handleChange("no_telp")}
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("no_telp")}
                      value={values.no_telp}
                      errors={errors}
                      touched={touched}
                    />

                    <InputText
                      name="email"
                      label="Email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("email")}
                      value={values.email}
                      errors={errors}
                      touched={touched}
                    />
                    <InputText
                      name="alamat"
                      label="Alamat"
                      placeholder="Alamat"
                      onChangeText={handleChange("alamat")}
                      onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("alamat")}
                      value={values.alamat}
                      errors={errors}
                      touched={touched}
                    />

                    <Button
                      title="Buat Akun"
                      variant="primary"
                      size="lg"
                      width="100%"
                      loading={loading_btn}
                      onPress={handleSubmit}
                    />
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
```

I want to take the value of datepicker item into the textinput value, but i don understand to make it. I set the value of text input with moment package and then call (date) , to call the date of datepicker, but couldnt find the value.

[image]